# WooCommerce Product Import not using Variation Products ID's

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using a CSV to update product pricing rather than using the WooCommerce UI. The product ID's are respected and will be skipped by the Importer. Product Variations on the other hand do not have their ID's respected and the system will create new versions of the variations whenever I run the importer. This could be a problem as I want the Importer to not generate new product variations if the user uploading the CSV forgets to tick "Update Existing Products".

I have tried using the CSV to create the variations and then backfilling their ID's into the CSV. This did not help and instead the system still created new Product Variations for each Variant

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Turns out WooCommerce just seemingly ignores the ID column and relies entirely on each Variant having a unique SKU.

So I set-up an excel formula to generate a unique SKU for each product and now it works as expected.